# Is this a dataframe, and if so how do I read it?

Tags: r

R is ruling me today instead of the other way round.

I have a variable which seems to be a list with the first element as a dataframe:

```
>   member1  
[[1]]
      id  name
1 561389 Music

>   str(member1)
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ id  : int 561389
  ..$ name: chr "Music"
```

How can I see if the "name" variable == "Music"?

Comment: As it is a `list` of 1 data.frame, just do `d1 <- member1[[1]]` to extract the `list` element. `d1$name == 'Music'` or without creatiing an object `member1[[1]]$name == 'Music'`

Comment: Or  since it is a data.frame,  `member1$name1`

Comment: `member1$name[1]`